# fab file run/ openshell commands fail at modified shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

Fabfile has served me well on multiple linux hosts, but I am stuck here with a specific host from Sonus which probably has modified shell and thus there's a small delay after logging into the shell and I see that there's no response for my commands.

I have tried using both run and open_shell variants and command options like --no-pty and --linewise but I am not sure what's the root cause and fix for solving the fabfile problem with modified shell. Any guidance here will be very much helpful.

See below output from interaction:

```
[keshav@home ~]$ fab -f ~/script/Sonus.py lab test
[sonus.lab.com] Executing task 'test'
[sonus.lab.com] run: date
[sonus.lab.com] out: Unauthorized access to this system is forbidden by; "The Team."  Any unauthorized access; is punishable by; "The Team!!!!!."  
[sonus.lab.com] out: admin connected from 10.X.Y.Z using ssh on Sonuss
[sonus.lab.com] out:
[sonus.lab.com] out: Your last successful login was at 2016-10-12 7:24:10
[sonus.lab.com] out:
[sonus.lab.com] out: Your last successful login was from 10.X.Y.Z
[sonus.lab.com] out: admin@Sonuss> exit
[sonus.lab.com] out:
```

Done.
Disconnecting from sonus.lab.com... done.

Comment: Fabric use ssh for communication to the server. Perhaps your remote host is running a modified open-ssh server, or another implementation like dropbear. I think you should login manually and get a process list, investigate further about binary versions installed on that system.

Comment: Thanks Tomas. Yep..they have covered up linux bash..I can't run any bash commands to find out what's going on in it.